# Use of verb forget and adverb constitute a collocation?

Tags: verbs, adverbs, syntactic-analysis, semantics

My question relates to the following passage/excerpt produced by a participant (an EFL learner) of my MA study:

> "I forgot my laptop on the bus".

I had three raters analysing accuracy (one is a native speaker). The sentence above was the source of a discussion that has not reached an end.  According to one of the raters (native speaker) there is a syntactic issue with the sentence. The correct would be: *"I left my laptop on the bus."* Well, I really could not find an explanation for that.

If there is a issue I would say it is of a semantic order, but not syntactic. To make things worse I then asked a fourth rater (native speaker too) to evaluate the sentence and this last rater said the sentence is correct.

Comment: The use of the locative PP here is perhaps infelicitous, but it is semantically OK (I understood it immediately), and only marginally ungrammatical (if at all). We could interpret it as, Q: "Where did you forget your laptop"? A: "I forgot it on the bus". There are obvious and better alternatives of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, this would be a question of semantics and not syntax. Although *leave* would also be correct, *forget* is also a valid option that the speaker who took issue with the usage was possibly not familiar with. See below for the third definition of the transitive usage of [*forget*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/forgotten) from Dictionary.com.

> *forget* - to leave behind unintentionally; neglect to take

---

Updating my answer after reading the comment that the question is if the use of an adverbial phrase describing where the book was left/forgotten is correct. I can see the argument – the forgetting didn't necessarily happen in one place. However, when you use *forgot* to mean *unintentionally left* you can very easily add an adverb for the place where it was left. See [this n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forgot+my+wallet+at%2C+left+my+wallet+at&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforgot%20my%20wallet%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20my%20wallet%20at%3B%2Cc0) from Google books of how often "forgot my wallet at" and "left my wallet at" are used throughout the years. It's clear *left my wallet at* is more common, but do keep in mind it does not have exactly the same meaning, as you can purposefully leave your wallet somewhere. Nevertheless, it shows that for at least some dialects of English, the syntax of such a construction is valid.

Comment: Thanks, Nolan. Well, the rater pointed out that the sentence would be correct if it was :"I forgot my laptop.". What he said is that you cannot add " on the bus", that is, the adverb if I am not wrong. So, the issue is not linked to the transitive aspect but the possibility or adding an adverb to it.

Comment: *Forget* doesn't typically take a locative phrase. When there is one, it would normally identify the place you were supposed to have brought the laptop to. "I forgot my laptop on my trip to Boston." You can escape this by adding "back". "I forgot my laptop back on the bus". This is in contrast to *left*, which carries a much higher expectation of a locative phrase.

Comment: @PhilSweet, you are correct that *left* does have a higher expectation of a locative phrase, but the assertion that the locative phrase for *forgot* must describe the location you intended to take the item does not seem to hold, at least in colloquial speech. Can you find a reputable source supporting your assertion? I'm not saying you can't use the locative phrase in that way; I'm just saying I don't believe it is restricted to such usage.

Comment: @Nolan I didn't say that it must. I said you can disambiguate the problem by adding *back*.

Comment: @PhilSweet I apologize, I must have misread, but still, can you provide a source that locative phrases used with *forget* (in the usage we're discussing) normally specify where the item should have been taken and not where it was left?